# Accept and forward incoming IPv6 range to another interface

Tags: routing, openvpn, ipv6, firewalld

I have an OpenVPN setup working with IPv4. In preparation for IPv6 support, I did the following:

- ens3 interface (can reach Internet) got a /64 address from ISP
- I split the /64 into two /65
- ens3 now has ....::/65
- OpenVPN server is configured to use ....:8000::/65
- hence tun0 (OpenVPN device) has ....:8000::1/65
- when clients connect, they get addresses from the proper range assigned, e.g. ....:8000::1000/65

The problem: IPv6 communication only works in outgoing direction. Inbound traffic does not work, because ISP gateway asks for example `ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has ....:8000::1000` which arrives on ens3 but my server does not respond to this. I guess I have to tell my server and ens3 to accept packets for the ....:8000::/65 range and forward it to tun0?! But I'm not sure how to do this.

In case this is relevant, I use firewalld on a Fedora machine.

**EDIT**

After @kasperd pointed me to a good explanation of routed prefixes, I went on reading about this.

I haven't found documentation on how I can request a routed prefix from my hosting provider. So I guess I have to stay with my self-split /65 prefixes. Please tell me how to improve if this is not a clean solution!

In order to answer to the mentioned neighbor solicitations, one needs to enable NDP proxying. `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1`

For a fixed number of clients, one could now do `ip neigh add proxy ....:8000::1000 dev ens3`. To automate this process with OpenVPN, one can add the following two lines to the OpenVPN server config:

```
script-security 2
learn-address ./proxy-ndp
```

With `proxy-ndp` script beeing

```
#!/bin/bash

extif=ens3

op="$1"
addr="$2"

if [[ "$addr" != *":"* ]]; then
    # no IPv6
    exit 0
fi

case "$op" in
    add|update)
        /usr/sbin/ip neigh replace proxy "$addr" dev "$extif"
        ;;
    delete)
        /usr/sbin/ip neigh del proxy "$addr" dev "$extif"
        ;;
esac
```

Additionally, if IPv6 forwarding isn't already present, one should enable this with `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`. The last step is to allow forwarding between the network interfaces. Since I use firewalld, the command is `firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter FORWARD 0 -i tun0 -o ens3 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPv6: differences between "routed prefix" and "link prefix"?](http://serverfault.com/questions/684455/ipv6-differences-between-routed-prefix-and-link-prefix)

Comment: thx, with a lot of additional research, I found a solution, see my edit. If this splitting thing is not clean, please tell me how to improve.

Comment: get a /60 from your upstream

Comment: I'm interested in the reasoning behind this advice. Is it because splitting in smaller parts than \64 is considered bad practice?

Comment: @firefexx Link prefixes are supposed to be /64. If you have a link prefix of any other length, you are doing it wrong. Additionally a link prefix and a routed prefix behave differently, and you should be using the correct type for the task you need to solve.

Comment: Ok. I'm wondering why halve of the address belongs to a single link and shouldn't be split. Looks like a waste of addresses. But fine.

How does one get a routed prefix from upstream? Is this a technical procedure simply issuing something via DHCPv6 or does one need to ask the upstream if they would configure an exception?

Comment: Your hosting provider (which [you should explicitly name](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)) should proactively provide you with sufficient IPv6 space. Using less than a /64 for a link breaks a lot of various IPv6 bits. You may call this "a waste" but it's intentional: IPv6 is intended to have more than enough space for everyone to have as many subnets as they need, and as many hosts on a subnet, for several centuries or longer. I've routed /57 to my personal OpenVPN server and probably won't run out... A provider _not_ giving you enough subnets is doing it wrong. See also RFC 6177.